# Generating taxonomy or text representation of Neo4j Query Result

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I loaded a CSV based taxonomy into Neo4j where each node represents a hierarchical placement in Neo4j. In other words, each node has a parent_of and child_of relationship based on whether it is a subset or superset of the hierarchy.

Example taxonomy:

```
Ambiguous, Moon
Aerospace and electronic systems
Aerospace and electronic systems, Moon
Aerospace and electronic systems, Aerospace engineering, Satellites, Moon, Man on the Moon
```

Example nodes:

```
Moon
Ambiguous
```

Where "Moon" is a child_of "Ambiguous" and "Ambiguous" is a parent_of "Moon" etc.

Now I would like to search for a specific node in the DB and re-create its taxanomical heirarchy based on the search results.

So first I ran the cypher query:

```
MATCH (n)-[:PARENT_TO*]->(m) where m.term = "Man on the Moon" RETURN n,m;
```

and got the following:

[image]

[image]

My Question/Problem is:

The table version presents only an "n" and "m" mapping. I am not able to infer any level of depth between the terms - so I can't re-create the hierarchy.

So, how can I use a search and query results to re-generate multi-level hierarchies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return the entire path between nodes:

```
MATCH path = (n)-[:PARENT_TO*]->(m) where m.term = "Man on the Moon" 
RETURN nodes( path )
```

Comment: Is it always the case that the last row in the response is the full path? (thanks for the answer btw!)

Comment: Also, I accepted the answer, but there is still a problem. The results don't clearly state which groups are full paths - so I really can't re-create the taxonomy from the results. Or can I?

Comment: @Sean What do you mean "re-create the taxonomy"? Can you give an example of what you want to get?